# Pterodactyl boy - YA novel

Tags: story-identification

1980s American YA fantasy novel about a boy who has a tame pterodactyl. It wears a harness that allows it to tow him through the air (this is on the cover.) Details: There is no explanation as to why pterodactyls and humans exist side-by-side. As far as I can remember there were no other dinosaurs present. The boy belongs to a human/pterodactyl tribe, but he has been separated from them in some fashion - he has been living by himself in the desert, and it is his decision to leave that begins the novel. I can't remember anything about the actual plot.

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/153862.Captain_Underpants_and_the_Preposterous_Plight_of_the_Purple_Potty_People

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pterodactyls-Egg-Annie-Besant/dp/9351365220